# What will Max return from an empty record?

Tags: django, django-views

what will the max return if particular customer has no order__id, below is the code in views.py in django,

```
queryset = Customer.objects.annotate(last_order_id=Max('order__id'))
```

[screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imiv1.png)

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, as per the last column in the attached screenshot, it has returned "None". But there is no such documentation reference that I have found.